# Deploying Nodejs app on the windows server

Tags: node.js, angular, deployment, hosting

I am building an realtime chat application with server side Noe and client side angular with socket.io. As i am new to Node, I jave not deployed any Node App before.. I am very confused on how to host my app on a windows server...

Step by step guide will be really helpful..

Answer (score 1):

Please follow [this article](https://harveywilliams.net/blog/installing-iisnode) to get going. Primary requirement to run your Node.js app on Windows is the `iisnode` module. If you follow the instructions carefully, you can get it working pretty quickly. `iisnode` module takes care of all the life cycle of the node.js app on Windows IIS.